# Ionic execute code when app is launched during splash screen and before device ready event

Tags: events, ionic-framework

I have a ionic 3 app and want to execute code to get my user data just when app is launched, when the splash screen is showing and the app pages have not yet been rendered.

I currently do this when app has fired the appReady event but am interested if I can win another 2 seconds witch usually takes during the splash screen.

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private platform: Platform,
              private storage: Storage) {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.storage.get('id_token').then((token) => {
    this.initUserData(token);
  });
});

  }
}
```